# cambiar comas por puntos de un excel

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy tomando un archivo de excel y quiero generar otro nuevo pero quiero cambiar las comas por puntos y que se muestre en el excel nuevo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías agregar lo que intentaste hasta ahora para lograrlo por favor? Agrega a la pregunta un código en el que intentes hacer eso mismo, aunque no funcione. De ese modo será mejor recibida por la comunidad y no parecerá que pides que te hagamos la tarea.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. 
Lo ideal es compartir  lo que has intentado hacer. Para manejarte en el sitio  
 lee que tipos de preguntas debo evitar asi evitas que tu pregunta sea eliminada o reportada
preguntas constructivas son por ejemplo aquellas que inspiran respuestas que expliquen el porque y el como
e invitan a compartir experiencias respaldadas con hechos y referencias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la opcion `converters` de pd.read_excel

```
def conversor_decimal(valor):
    try:
        return float(valor.replace(',', '.'))
    except ValueError:
        return valor

archivo_excel = pd.read_excel('archivo.xslx', converters={ 'debito': conversor_decimal, 'credito': conversor_decimal, 'saldo': conversor_decimal })
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono